# Cronjob for rebooting everyday

Tags: cron, reboot

I have set this cronjob because I want my server to be rebooted everyday at 05:00

```
# file: /etc/cron.d/reboot
* 5 * * * root reboot &> /dev/null
```

I think it worked the first time as I was kicked out of the ssh connection. But now I came back some days later and found this:

```
$ uptime
07:12:13 up 7 days
```

Does this mean that it hasn't rebooted in 7 days? What is wrong?

Comment: If you server is still up&running and healthy after 7 days uptime, why on earth do you want to reboot it daily?

Comment: @Mat Because I don't want surprises. Sometimes it goes down, and then it takes hours to come back. The delay in coming back only happens when it's been up for too long. So I prefer to reboot everyday at 5 am when there aren't many visits (it's a web server). It comes back so fast that it manages to answer pending requests before they time out. I'm not a sysadmin, so there might be a better way obviously. But right now I need this.

Comment: Note that while this doesn't explain your issue, your crontab is *wrong*. It'll fire every minute between 5am and 6am. Change the first `*` to a `0`.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Removed the whole "don't do that" discussion, since it got a bit long without actually solving anything

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper I'd guess that sometimes taking a while to come back is a fsck being forced after X days. Unfortunately, rebooting daily won't actually stop that. In fact, there is also a fsck after Y mounts, so it'll make it happen more. You can change this with tune2fs (if you're using ext2/3/4).

Comment: I am surprised to see that the question is downvoted this hard. Admittedly, it's not the best way to administer a web server (which I agree with,) yet the question is a legit one, which motivated the answer below that solved my problem. Had it been asked in a shorter version: "why does this cron directive doesn't reboot my computer: * 5 * * * root reboot &> /dev/null", it probably wouldn't be downvoted. The dislike are simply directed toward the background that the op provided to justify his/her choice. I find it a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the other commentators said, if `uptime` reports 7 days of uptime, the system hasn't rebooted in that while.

Besides @Dennis' correct comment, remove the pipe to `/dev/null` temporarily, then check `root`'s mail and `/var/log/syslog`.

If the `reboot` command is not on the executing shell's `PATH`, cron might simply not find it.

Some systems don't have the `reboot` command, in which case you'd need to use `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a MTA configured so I tried redirecting the output to a file. I had to use the absolute path to reboot, that worked fine.

Comment: "If the reboot command is not on the executing shell's PATH, cron might simply not find it" that nailed it in my issue. Changing it to /sbin/reboot solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `&>` syntax for redirecting both stderr and stdout works in bash, but it likely doesn't work in `/bin/sh`, which is used to execute `cron` commands.

Try this:

```
0 5 * * * root reboot > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This also fixes the timing error pointed out by Dennis Kaarsemaker's comment.

(I'm not commenting on whether this is a good idea in the first place.)

Comment: Now we are talking! I'm gonna try this, thanks

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: `>&` and `&>` both work in bash; only `>&` works in csh and tcsh. Since the question uses `&>`, and csh and tcsh aren't relevent, I've deleted the reference to them.

Comment: What does the**2>&1** stand for?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: `>/dev/null` discards standard output. `2>&1` directs stderr to the same place, so all output is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer I can give you is to get a sysadmin who can find out what's wrong with the box and why reboots take so long. All other possible solutions to your "problem" (such as checking `$PATH`, using the absolute path to `reboot` or using `shutdown -r`) are merely workarounds that will make your cronjob work but keep you blind as to what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for the `cron` you have installed. It can do various things, depending on the implementation - like setting only specific variables (i.e. not `PATH`, which could cause `reboot` not to be found) before performing the required action.

Apart from the incorrect first asterix in time definition, I believe the "root" string is incorrect, and the file should look like:

```
# file: /etc/cron.d/reboot
0 5 * * * reboot &> /dev/null
```

otherwise it fails since it tries to call `root` with argument `reboot`.
If you want to set root's crontab, you have to run the `crontab` (or whatever you use to set the jobs specification) command as root.

Comment: The files in /etc/cron.d have the same format as /etc/crontab which has a username after the time spec.

Comment: @Iain thanks, I somehow didn't notice this.